# Caching Feeds from Facebook, Twitter & Instagram

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, twitter, instagram

I'm building a site for a non-profit festival where we'd like to have a 'media' page which brings in photos from instagram (hashtag search), updates and photos from Facebook (via festival's albums) twitter posts (by user and hashtag).

I've tried the JS widgets for Facebook and Twitter but wondered about using PHP/Codeigniter to pull the feeds and caching them somehow for better performance and more control over the look.

Would it be best to then store the feed data in a json file on the server or in a MySQL record?

I'm leaning toward a table with a record for each feed that would basically just store the feed URL, JSON, last updated time and an identifier of some sort.

Then I could write a class with the following type of methods:

```
get_feed($id='facebook_updates', $expiry_time=3600);
```

1. Does this seem like a reasonable way to go? or is there a better solution already existing?
2. I'm not quite sure how I'd work that in with the feeds that need Auth (twitter & Instagram)

Answer (score 1):

bro!

First, it does seem a reasonable way to do it and I don't know any better.
But, if I had to accomplish that, I would break my problem in two:

- A server side code to grab the info from the services (that I would
  probably store as json so that I could use the info returned
  directly) running with cronjobs from time to time.
- A client side (server would work too) one to show that info with
  customized style.

To work with the feeds that need auth, you'll have to create an app in each of them, authorize it to access your personal account and use it in the code. Never worked with Instagram but the others have good documentation on how to do that.

Finally, with some modification, you may be able to use this wonderful too to help you accomplish your task: http://plugins.in1.com/socialist